ATmega32: Bitshifting in the Code changes the Interrupt Overflow Duration
In our C Code we are Bitshifting a 1:
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 3) //This statement is True, and this LED is Switched correctly
    {
        PORTC |= (1 << led);
    }

This somehow messes with the Overflow Interrupt that is inverting a LED on PORTC:
/***INTERUPT*/
ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect)
{
    PORTC ^= 0x02;
    TCNT2 = 0;
}

This seems to not Switch the LED (Not the same as the one above) at a regular intervall.
I Uploadet the whole Code here for Reference: https://pastebin.com/X1GhvVXc
In the Process of finding out what the Problem could be, we tried replacing this:
int LED_MODUL_An(uint8_t led)
{
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 1)
    {
        PORTA |= (1 << led);
    }
    
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 2)
    {
        PORTB |= (1 << led);
    }
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 3)
    {
        PORTC |= (1 << led);
    }
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 4)
    {
        PORTD |= (1 << led);
    }
    return 0;
}

int LED_MODUL_Aus(uint8_t led)
{
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 1)
    {
        PORTA &= ~(1 << led);
    }
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 2)
    {
        PORTB &= ~(1 << led);
    }
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 3)
    {
        PORTC &= ~(1 << led);
    }
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 4)
    {
        PORTD &= ~(1 << led);
    }
    return 0;
}

With this:
int LED_MODUL_An(uint8_t led)
{
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 1)
    {
        PORTA |= 1;
    }
    
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 2)
    {
        PORTB |= 1;
    }
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 3)
    {
        PORTC |= 1;
    }
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 4)
    {
        PORTD |= 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int LED_MODUL_Aus(uint8_t led)
{
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 1)
    {
        PORTA &= 0xFE;
    }
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 2)
    {
        PORTB &= 0xFE;
    }
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 3)
    {
        PORTC &= 0xFE;
    }
    if(posizion_LED_MODUL == 4)
    {
        PORTD &= 0xFE;
    }
    return 0;
}

This fixed the irregular blinking and the LED now blinked at regular intervalls. But we don't know why a bit shift in another Function would disturb the Interrupt.
We are using Microchip Studio with the built in compiler.
The Fuses are set like this:
Image of the Fuses Tab
If any of you have suggestions to fix the Problem, we would be very thankfull.

Your replacement functions are not semantically equivalent to the originals, except when the led parameter has value 0.

Since the led in your presumably original code (from the pastebin) is always zero, the two snippets you have posted are equivalent and I don't see how interchanging them can affect the behavior. Looks like you are not telling us the whole story.

In your posted code, you always call LED_MODUL_An() with a value of 0. Is this the real code, or is there more? My real question is, is it possible that LED_MODUL_An() is being called when led has other values, particularly 1?

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and provide a [mre] with the emphasis on minimal and complete. You are supposed to provide the source in the question, not at some random external resource. While you are extending your question, please add the assembly listing, as it will most probably show the problem.

Depending on your compiler's options on optimization, the statements with shift expressions are compiled into read-modify-write sequences, but the statement with literals are compiled into single instructions to set or reset a bit.

@thebusybee I'd imagine the PORTx are defined something like *(volatile uint8_t*)0x1000, so I'd expect it to always be read-modify-write, unless this compiler is blatantly non-conforming.

@EugeneSh. Why do you think that instructions setting/resetting a single bit in a port/register are a non-conforming realization, if the 8-bit port/register is volatile?

@thebusybee I might have misunderstood that you said tbh. Were you speaking of the evaluation of the RHS expression (either containing shift or not)? I was referring to the fact that the register access will be RMW in any case. Are you saying that the extra shift instruction is visibly changing the timing? I would be very surprised if that's the case.

The problem is the variable shift amount in the first case. The compiler needs to calculate the pattern to reset and to set, respectively, the desired bit. Because this results in a variable value, the compiler cannot generate an atomic instruction. Instead it produces code to read the port register, to modify the value with the variable pattern, and finally to write the result back to the port register.
In contrast, if you use a constant shift amount, the compiler is able to generate a single instruction, because it knows the bit to reset and to set, respectively.
See this minimal example:
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void reset_with_variable(uint8_t led)
{
    PORTA &= ~(1 << led);
}

void set_with_variable(uint8_t led)
{
    PORTA |= 1 << led;
}

void reset_with_constant(void)
{
    PORTA &= ~1;
}

void set_with_constant(void)
{
    PORTA |= 1;
}

The compilation with optimization results in the following assembly code. I have marked the accesses to the port register.
__SP_H__ = 0x3e
__SP_L__ = 0x3d
__SREG__ = 0x3f
__tmp_reg__ = 0
__zero_reg__ = 1
reset_with_variable(unsigned char):
.L__stack_usage = 0
        in r25,0x1b     ; <- READ
        ldi r18,lo8(1)
        ldi r19,0
        rjmp 2f
        1:
        lsl r18
        2:
        dec r24
        brpl 1b
        com r18
        and r18,r25     ; <- MODIFY
        out 0x1b,r18    ; <- WRITE
        ret
set_with_variable(unsigned char):
.L__stack_usage = 0
        in r25,0x1b     ; <- READ
        ldi r18,lo8(1)
        ldi r19,0
        rjmp 2f
        1:
        lsl r18
        2:
        dec r24
        brpl 1b
        or r25,r18      ; <- MODIFY
        out 0x1b,r25    ; <- WRITE
        ret
reset_with_constant():
.L__stack_usage = 0
        cbi 0x1b,0      ; <- READ-MODIFY-WRITE
        ret
set_with_constant():
.L__stack_usage = 0
        sbi 0x1b,0      ; <- READ-MODIFY-WRITE
        ret

It is worse than I expected, because the compiler puts all the pattern calculation code between the read instruction and the write instruction, widening the interval between both.
Anyway, what we commonly expect is an atomic read-modify-write. But the CPU does not provide such an instruction for variable patterns.
Now the error happens: During the interval calculating the pattern to modify the read value, an interrupt occurs. Its service routine modifies the port register, as expected, and correctly. But after the interrupt service routine returns to the interrupted sequence, r25 still has the previous value of the port register. This one is modified by the pattern and written back to the port register. The modification by the interrupt service routine is reverted.
The longer the interval, the higher the probability for the error to happen.
In the case with constant shift amounts the problem does not exist, because the compiler generates a single instruction, which cannot be interrupted and is therefore atomic.

Now, how do you solve the issue?
You need to see the single C statement as a critical section, which is executed by multiple assembly instructions.
One possible solution is to disable the interrupts during the C statement. This will postpone the possible execution of the interrupt service until the section is left.
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void reset_with_variable(uint8_t led)
{
    cli();
    PORTA &= ~(1 << led);
    sei();
}

void set_with_variable(uint8_t led)
{
    cli();
    PORTA |= (1 << led);
    sei();
}


Lesson to learn: If you encounter such "strange" problems, look into the generated assembly code. You will need to learn to read and understand assembly at least a bit, but it will raise your understanding very much.
